# Jersey Path annotation not mapping all file types

Tags: java, jersey

I am attempting to map jersey requests to retrieve an image using the following mapping. The following works for paths suchs as

- /test/file.png
- /test/file.gif
- /test/file.jpeg

But it fails to map for

- /test/file.jpg

I have no other mappings than this one so it cannot be conflicting with another mapping. Why would Jersey be unable to map a path inluding a .jpg?

```
@GET
@Path("/{pathPrefix}/{file}")
public Response getImage(@PathParam("pathPrefix") String pathPrefix,
                         @PathParam("file") String file
```

Comment: what did you put under xml file

Comment: goodness you found the problem! i had jpg listed as a WebPageContentRegex and didn't even know it. I will put that in as the answer. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my web.xml I found the following line that had "jpg" listed as WebPageContentRegex. removing that value from the set of content solved the problem

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
    <param-value>.*\.(html|ico|jsp|jpg|css)</param-value>
</init-param>
```